# Issue with adding a new option to all select elements in javascript by looping

Tags: javascript, loops, selectors-api

I want to add a new option onto all the existing dropdown menus in my page. I get all the menus using querySelectorAll and loop through each and add the option.

```
// creating my option
let opt;
opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.value = 10;
opt.text = 'hello';

// looping and adding the option
document.querySelectorAll('select').forEach(ele => {
  ele.add(opt);
});
```

However the issue is only last dropdown list is getting this option added to it. All the preceding selects are not affected.
Why?
However if I create the new option within the loop as shown below, all the select lists get updated as intended

```
document.querySelectorAll('select').forEach(ele => {
let opt;
opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.value = 10;
opt.text = 'hello';
ele.add(opt);
});
```

Why is it like this? Please help.

Comment: Because it is the same opt you move around

Answer (score 1):

Although This question already has answers here (that you need a new element for each add):

[forEach loop only creating last DOM element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65240839/foreach-loop-only-creating-last-dom-element)
[Why each() loop changes only the last element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72658191/why-each-loop-changes-only-the-last-element)
[appendChild in for loop only adds 1 child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730824/appendchild-in-for-loop-only-adds-1-child)
[Javascript Loop: inserting element only working on last iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421016/javascript-loop-inserting-element-only-working-on-last-iteration)

I will post my suggestion since it is simpler than the others

```js
let opt = new Option('10', 'hello');
const sels = document.querySelectorAll("select")
 .forEach(s => s.appendChild(opt.cloneNode(true)));
```

```html
<select name="one">
  <option value="1">One</option>
</select>
<select name="two">
  <option value="1">Two</option>
</select>
<select name="three">
  <option value="1">Three</option>
</select>
<select name="four">
  <option value="1">Four</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code did not work because `document.createElement("option")` was called only once and subsequently the same element was reassigned to a series of `select` elements. After the first time the same option was simply *moved* to the next select and not copied.

In contrast to that the following script makes use of the element method `.insertAdjacentHTML()` which creates new elements on the fly and adds them at the specified point.

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick=ev=>{
 document.querySelectorAll("select").forEach(s=>s.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",'<option value="10">hello</option>'));
}
```

```html
<select name="one"><option value="1">Start</option></select>
<select name="two"><option value="1">as you</option></select>
<select name="three"><option value="1">mean to</option></select>
<select name="four"><option value="1">go on!</option></select>
<br><button>add an option</button>
```